# "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user" in Openshift3

Tags: git, docker, openshift, tls1.2, s2i

If S2I - "Source-to-image" resource in Openshift3 tries to connect to a TLS Gitlab repository shows the following message: "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user".

How can I instruct Openshift3 which certificates authorities are able to use there? Is there any config/option to bypass this error?

The command entered was:

```
oc new-app tomcat~https://gitlab.xxx/test/test.git --name=test --strategy=docker
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For security reasons,  you should add a [trusted CA source secret](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-secrets-trusted-certificate-authorities) to the BuildConfig. To answer your question, you can disable TLS verification by setting an environment variable `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` to `false` in the BuildConfig. Checks the [docs here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/builds.html#trusted-certificate-authorities) for more info.

To pass this directly to the `oc new-app` command run `oc new-app --build-env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=false`

Comment: I read there's the environment variable GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY. How can I set this in Openshift?

Comment: You can set that as an environment variable in the buildconfig

Comment: Could you help me providing some sample? I tried using the command "oc new-app". I also facing the question how to inform user/password of GIT account.

Comment: if you run `oc get bc` whats the output from that?

Comment: NAME                 TYPE      FROM      LATEST
test                     Docker      Git             3

Comment: Ok try `oc set env bc/test GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=false` and restart the build

Comment: Yes, it has solved. But in this case I fixed it after receiving the error on "oc new-app". Is there any to instruct new-app at the same time?

Comment: Untested, but I would try `oc new-app --build-env=[GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=false]`

Comment: It did not work, see message: "error: invalid parameter assignment in "[GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=false]""

Comment: Ok try `oc new-app --build-env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=false`

Comment: That works, tks a lot! I also solve Git credentials issue creating a secret in Openshift and associating to the key "sourceSecret" in my BuildConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I'd suggest just importing the root CA such that TLS validation works.  Won't attempt to speak to all the reasons why this should be a **must**, but here's how you'd do it:

#### 1) Grab the root certificate file.

If you're running an internal Gitlab instance, whoever set it up should be able to point you to the root CA they're using.

#### 2) Create a new secret with the certificate file

```
#oc secrets new [secret name] ca.crt=[local .crt file]
oc secrets new tls-root-ca ca.crt=my-it-ca.crt
```

#### 3) Attach your newly created secret to the build config

```
    #oc patch bc/[build config name] --patch '{ "spec": {"source": { "sourceSecret": { "name": "[secret name]" } } } }'
    oc patch bc/my-build --patch '{ "spec": {"source": { "sourceSecret": { "name": "tls-root-ca" } } } }'
```

In case you're not familiar with the patch command, this is just adding a "sourceSecret" block like this:

```
  source:
    git:
      uri: https://your.gitlab.org/your-app
    sourceSecret:
      name: tls-root-ca
```

See also the [openshift guide on build input secrets](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-secrets-trusted-certificate-authorities)